# How to extract a specific value from stability selection model output

Tags: r, extract

I have the following summary output, and I would like to extract the result from selected variables (variable name only=X10).

```
>  stab.glmnet
    Stability Selection with unimodality assumption

Selected variables:
X10 
10 

Selection probabilities:
X2   X1   X7   X3   X6   X4   X5   X8   X9  X10 
0.02 0.06 0.20 0.22 0.25 0.32 0.35 0.37 0.41 1.00 

---
Cutoff: 0.75; q: 3; PFER (*):  0.918 
(*) or expected number of low selection probability variables
PFER (specified upper bound):  1 
PFER corresponds to signif. level 0.0918 (without multiplicity adjustment)
```

I tried (below) but it gives me only the other value which is 10

```
var <- stab.glmnet$selected[[1]]
```

The data:

```
set.seed(1001)
n <- 100
Y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
X1 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.4,0.5))
X2 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.25,0.25))
X3 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.4,0.4))
X4 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.35,0.35,0.3))
X5 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.7))
X6 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.1,0.1))
X7 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1,0.1,0.8))
X8 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.35,0.35,0.3))
X9 <- sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.35,0.35,0.3))
X10 <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,
2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,   
1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)

datasim <- data.frame(Y=as.factor(Y),X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10)
```

The packages and stability selection code

```
library("stabs")
library("glmnet")
x <- model.matrix(Y~.,datasim)[,-1]
y <- datasim$Y
y <- as.numeric(y)

stab.glmnet <- stabsel(x,y ,fitfun = glmnet.lasso, cutoff = 0.75,PFER = 1)
```

Comment: Which package and function did you use to create the model? More generally, you'll make it much easier for people to help you if you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: thank @eipi10 , I updated the question above

Comment: You don't say what you want to extract from the summary. Do you want the selection probabilities of the selected variables or something else?

Comment: please add a `set.seed(...)` before the first use of `sample` to make it reproducible and double check that it runs without error.  I get an error when I run it with `set.seed(123)`.

Comment: To run that final line of code without error, I had to change `y` from a factor to `as.numeric(y)`...  If you're trying to get the name of the selected variables, use the `names` function with `[` instead of `[[` (using `[[` cause the name to be dropped). `names(stab.glmnet$selected[1])`

Comment: thanks @jota it works.

Answer (score 3):

I get an error when I run your code. In any case, if you take a look at the `print.stabsel` function, you can see where in the model object each piece of summary output is located. The code for `print.stabsel` is pasted in below.

If you want, for example, the selection probabilities of the selected variables, you can see that the indices of the selected variables can be found in `stab.glmnet$selected`. The selection probabilities are in `stab.glmnet$max`. So we can do the following:

```
stab.glmnet$max[stab.glmnet$selected]
```

To see what else is in the model object, look at the output of `str(stab.glmnet)`.

Code for `print.stabsel`:

```
getAnywhere(print.stabsel)
```

> ```
> function (x, decreasing = FALSE, print.all = TRUE, ...) 
> {
>     cat("\tStability Selection")
>     if (x$assumption == "none") 
>         cat(" without further assumptions\n")
>     if (x$assumption == "unimodal") 
>         cat(" with unimodality assumption\n")
>     if (x$assumption == "r-concave") 
>         cat(" with r-concavity assumption\n")
>     if (length(x$selected) > 0) {
>         cat("\nSelected variables:\n")
>         print(x$selected)
>     }
>     else {
>         cat("\nNo variables selected\n")
>     }
>     cat("\nSelection probabilities:\n")
>     if (print.all) {
>         print(sort(x$max, decreasing = decreasing))
>     }
>     else {
>         print(sort(x$max[x$max > 0], decreasing = decreasing))
>     }
>     cat("\n---\n")
>     print.stabsel_parameters(x, heading = FALSE)
>     cat("\n")
>     invisible(x)
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you @eipi10 for your answer. So useful. I missed the as.numeric(y). Sorry for that. I want only the name of the selected variable. So I tried jota's suggestion (above) names(stab.glmnet$selected[1]) which gave me what I want, only the variable name "X10".